# The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'. in 3rd party api controller

Tags: javascript, .net, api, http, controller

I used a 3rd party plugin that sends a POST request api controller and getting this error

> "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."

.NET Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public WebApiResponseModel HandleContactForm(ContactFormViewModel model);
```

javascript

```
 $.ajax({
        url: "/Api/ContactForm/HandleContactForm/",
        type: "POST",
        data: object
        success: function (result) {
           ////result here
                  },
        error: function (data) {
            //// right data error here
        }
    });
```

The controller is using library System.Web.Mvc. I can't edit it to replace to System.Web.Http becuase it is a 3rd party controller and placed in a dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I already resolved this by adding mail settings in the web.config

```
<mailSettings>

  <smtp from="test@test.com">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="testuser" password="testpassword" enableSsl="true" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```